# @OneToMany Entity Relationship not filling the list in the entity

Tags: jpa, glassfish, entity, one-to-many

I have asked a similar question these days, and after many many hours of trials and fails i find myself compelled to describe my problem from a different point of view.

So I have two entities, `WaiterEntity` and `OrderEntity` - as logic demands it, a waiter can have many orders, but an order just one waiter. When the method that persists orders is called, the given order is persisted correctly into the database. But when the waiter is asked about his orders with `getOrders()`, an empty list is returned. I tried to solve this like many tutorials tell, by (right after persisting the order) getting the list of orders from the waiter and adding the order to the list. Unfortunately there is very strange behaviour to observe: adding the line `waiter.getOrders().add(order)` somehow prevents or reverts the order to be persisted into the database. But when I try to get the waiter's orders, the all orders that previously were tried to persist appear correctly in the database, but at once the tables of `WaiterEntity` and `OrderEntity` become unreadable for JPA. (Although, I can still see the correct table contents through manually called SQL queries.) The only thing that helps is rebuilding the tables.

So maybe some properties of `persistence.xml` are wrong? The entity annotations are not correctly set up? Or the java code is invalid as I can't tell because I don't have much experience with JPA and GlassFish?

Here are the Entities:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="WAITERENTITY")
public class WaiterEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "waiter_id")
    private List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    ... getters and setters

}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="ORDERENTITY")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long orderNumber;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name = "table_id")
    private TableEntity table_;

    private int sumOfMoney = 0;

    private boolean finalized = false;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<OrderItemEntity> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn (name = "waiter_id")
    private WaiterEntity waiter;

    ... getters and setters

}
```

The method to create orders:

```
public void create(OrderEntity e) {
    WaiterEntity waiter = null;
    if (e.getWaiter() != null) {
        waiter = em.find(WaiterEntity.class, e.getWaiter().getId());
        if (waiter != null) e.setWaiter(waiter);
    }
    if (e.getTable() != null) {
        TableEntity table = em.find(TableEntity.class, e.getTable().getId());
        if (table != null) e.setTable(table);
    }
    em.persist(e);
    if (waiter != null) {
        waiter = em.find(WaiterEntity.class, e.getWaiter().getId());
        //waiter.getOrders().add(e);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the commented line only makes problems. Further on, without this line, everything in the database is as it should be, as in the foreign keys are set up right, but an obtained `WaiterEntity` has an empty list, regardless that in fact it has orders in its relationship in the database.

**edit:** The method that gets a waiter's orders:

```
public List<OrderEntity> findOrdersByWaiter(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
    WaiterEntity waiter = em.find(WaiterEntity.class, id);
    return waiter.getOrders();
}
```

As mentioned, in the situation when the commented line above is un-commented, the strage behaviour starts when calling `findOrdersByWaiter(waiter.getId())`.

Furthermore, no exceptions are thrown by GlassFish. It's like it just does nothing anymore when calling persitence methods that work with the tables of `WaiterEntity` and/or `OrderEntity`.

It would really help if someone more experienced told me what I am doing wrong. If further explanation or code snippets are needed for a better understanding of the situation, I will paste it here. Thanks in advance!

**edit 2:** *(@DonovanMuller)* First, a little explanation why there are different object types: I use web resources. The client program and server program communicate using JSON. Only the server knows entity models and persists them. The client does the following (I am not posting all it's methods, just the relevant ones):

```
    IWaiterWebAppClient client = new IWaiterWebAppClient();
    client.create(new WaiterBean("John Marston"));
    client.create(new WaiterBean("Abigail Marston"));
    WaiterBean waiter = client.findByNameSingle(WaiterBean.class, "John Marston");
    int rnd = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    client.create(new TableBean(rnd));
    TableBean table = client.findByNameSingle(TableBean.class, String.valueOf(rnd));
    OrderBean order = new OrderBean(waiter);
    order.setWaiter(null);
    client.create(order);
    client.create(new OrderBean(waiter, table));
    System.out.println(waiter.getName() + "'s OrderBeans:\n" + client.findOrdersByWaiter(waiter.getId()));
```

while `client` is an instance of:

```
public class IWaiterWebAppClient {

    private final WebTarget webTarget;
    private final Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/iWaiter_WebAppServer/webresources";

    public IWaiterWebAppClient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("iwaiter");
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }

    public <T> void create(T bean) {
        webTarget.path(getResourcePath(bean.getClass()))
                .request()
                .post(Entity.entity(bean,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"));
    }

    public <T> T findByNameSingle(Class<T> type, String name) {
        List<T> list = findByName(type, name);
        return (!list.isEmpty() ? list.get(0) : null);
    }

    public <T> List<T> findByName(Class<T> type, String name) {
        return webTarget.path(getResourcePath(type) + "/findbyname/{name}")
                .queryParam("name", name).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(constructGenericTypeArrayList(type));
    }

    public List<OrderBean> findOrdersByWaiter(long id) {
        List<OrderBean> list = webTarget.path("order/findbywaiter/{id}")
                .queryParam("id", id).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<ArrayList<OrderBean>>() {});
        return list;
    }

    private String getResourcePath(Class c) {
        if (c.equals(EmployeeView.class)) return "employee";
        if (c.equals(WaiterBean.class)) return "waiter";
        if (c.equals(TableBean.class)) return "table";
        if (c.equals(ItemBean.class)) return "availableitem";
        if (c.equals(OrderBean.class)) return "order";
        return "";
    }

    ...
}
```

The fields, getters and setters of `WaiterBean` and `WaiterEntity`, as well as `OrderBean` and `OrderEntity`, are the same. The only difference is that the 'beans' don't have JPA annotations.

**edit 3:** (*@DonovanMuller*) The server is a resource class which methods represent HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and exchange information with JSON. The methods of the server have resource annotations, such as:

```
@GET @Path("order/findbywaiter/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<OrderEntity> findOrdersByWaiter(@QueryParam("id") long id) { ... }
```

**edit 4:** (*@DonovanMuller*) This is the main part of the web resource class that is responsible for persistence:

```
@Path("iwaiter")
@Stateless
public class IWaiterResource {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ZZZ_WebServicePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    @POST @Path(PATH_WAITER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void create(WaiterEntity e) { em.persist(e); }

    @POST @Path(PATH_ORDER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void create(OrderEntity e) {
        WaiterEntity waiter = e.getWaiter();
        em.persist(e);
        if (waiter != null) {
            waiter.getOrders().add(e);
        }
    }

    @PUT @Path(PATH_WAITER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void update(WaiterEntity e) { em.merge(e); }

    @PUT @Path(PATH_ORDER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void update(OrderEntity e) { em.merge(e); }

    @DELETE @Path(PATH_WAITER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void deleteWaiter(@QueryParam("id") long id) { em.remove(em.find(WaiterEntity.class, id)); }

    @DELETE @Path(PATH_ORDER)
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void deleteOrder(@QueryParam("id") long id) { em.remove(em.find(OrderEntity.class, id)); }

    private <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type) {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(type));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    @GET @Path(PATH_WAITER)
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<WaiterEntity> findAllWaiters() { return findAll(WaiterEntity.class); }

    @GET @Path(PATH_ORDER)
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<OrderEntity> findAllOrders() { return findAll(OrderEntity.class); }

    @GET @Path(PATH_WAITER + "/" + PATH_FIND_BY_ID + "/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public WaiterEntity findWaiter(@PathParam("id") long id) { return em.find(WaiterEntity.class, id); }

    @GET @Path(PATH_ORDER + "/" + PATH_FIND_BY_ID + "/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public OrderEntity findOrder(@PathParam("id") long id) { return em.find(OrderEntity.class, id); }

    private <T> List<T> findByName(Class<T> type, String column, String searchTag) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(type);
        Root<T> root = cq.from(type);
        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(column), searchTag));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    @GET @Path(PATH_WAITER + "/" + PATH_FIND_BY_NAME + "/{name}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<WaiterEntity> findWaitersByName(@QueryParam("name") String name) { return findByName(WaiterEntity.class, "name", name); }

    @GET @Path(PATH_ORDER + "/" + PATH_FIND_BY_NAME + "/{name}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<OrderEntity> findOrdersByName(@QueryParam("name") String name) { return findByName(OrderEntity.class, "orderNumber", name); }

    @GET @Path("order/findbywaiter/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<OrderEntity> findOrdersByWaiter(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
        WaiterEntity waiter = em.find(WaiterEntity.class, id);
        return waiter.getOrders();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that calls `create(OrderEntity e)`?

Comment: @donovanmuller I did now. I hope that's not too much information for the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was more referring to the 'server' side of things. I.e. the code (on the server side) that calls your `create(OrderEntity e)` method to persist the entities. Could you rather add that?

Comment: The server is a resource class which methods represent HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and exchange information with JSON. These methods are called by HTTP protocol and receive/send generated JSONs. See **edit 3** for details. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Yup, JAX-RS app, I get that. I'm interested in what code/resource calls `create(OrderEntity e)`. I want to see where the `OrderEntity e` parameter originates from and what transaction attributes have been set (if any). In fact, a small sample project that demonstrates your problem would be best (just the 'server' side), otherwise it's very difficult to get a good grasp of your problem.

Comment: @DonovanMuller There is no more than these HTTP methods server-side. I have only the `IWaiterResouce` class and the entity classes. I suppose GlassFish calls them automatically. I edited the topic with some more information about it, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your association is not mapped correctly. A bidirectional always has an *owner* side and an *inverse* side. In a OneToMany association, the inverse side **must** be the one side.

The inverse side does not specify how the association is mapped. It simply says: go look at the other side of the association to see how this association is mapped. This is done using the `mappedBy` attribute:

In Waiter:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "waiter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

In Order:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "waiter_id")
private WaiterEntity waiter;
```

The way you have done it, JPA considers `waiter.orders` and `order.waiter` as two independent associations, which, unfortunately, are mapped using the same join column. The two associations thus conflict with each other.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Your tip resolved the strange behaviour. Plus everything is still persisted correctly when `waiter.getOrders().add(e);` is called, but I have still the issue that later retrieval with `findOrdersByWaiter(long id) {...}` returns an empty list. In other words, the `add(e)` line is effectively doing nothing.

Comment: @jb-nizet I found it interesting that Hibernate and EclipseLink handle this differently. Hibernate seemed not to care whether the owner/inverse mappings were correctly defined or not, as it persisted exactly the same (and created the same tables) when using both variants. The only difference was that the queries generated by Hibernate were more efficient when having proper mapping as per your answer. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/donovanmuller/d9b06edc2bfb00e0fe64#file-orderservicetest-java) vs. this [gist](https://gist.github.com/donovanmuller/bd61d854ebcd4b26bd68#comment-1255026)

Comment: What would happen if you have 3 table/views and you have logical relations between them (FK's) but not in reality, they are just views. Anyway, you create Entities with this logical relations as it should be. But you don't have consistent data in DB. What would Spring JPA return for query? Exception?

Answer (score 0):

I moved this to an answer, as the comments were getting a bit long winded.
I haven't tested this but in your `create(OrderEntity e)` resource method (edit 4) your `waiter` reference is surely detached?

```
@POST @Path(PATH_ORDER)
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public void create(OrderEntity e) {
    WaiterEntity waiter = e.getWaiter(); // <-- getting a reference to a detached entity. I.e. not managed by the entity manager
    em.persist(e);
    if (waiter != null) {
        waiter.getOrders().add(e);
    }
}
```

If you change it to the following, does it solve your problem?

```
@POST @Path(PATH_ORDER)
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public void create(OrderEntity e) {
    em.persist(e);
    Waiter waiter = e.getWaiter(); // <-- The reference to the persisted OrderEntity is now managed
    if (waiter != null) {
        waiter.getOrders().add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid no, that doesn't change anything. The behaviour I described before stays the same as well, when `em.merge(waiter);` is called afterwards:

Comment: I'm afraid no, that doesn't change anything. The behaviour I described before in case `em.merge(waiter);` is called afterwards stays the same as well: no content ist persisted until `findOrdersByWaiter()` is called, after that call orders are persisted correctly, but the tables for `WaiterEntity` and `OrderEntity` become unreadable for JPA. By all means no further errors are reported in the GlassFish console, but the client (and the browser as well, when the web resource is requested manually) gets an HTTP internal server error 500.

Comment: What is the stacktrace if you wrap all code inside the resource method(s) that return 500 with a `try { ... } catch(Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }`?

Comment: As I said, there are no exceptions at all, apart from an error 500 reported from the client. The server just refuses to work with the 'corrupted' tables. As in, I tried to wrap everything in try-catch blocks, but it's no use.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error so somewhere an exception is being thrown (Tomcat for example returns a HTML page with the stack trace for 500's, does Glassfish not do that?) For some reason you're not seeing it. Which is why I suggested the try catch block as a last ditch effort to see what exception is being thrown. I'm afraid without a sample project that I can fiddle around with I don't think I'll be able to help you. If you can post one I'll be glad to have a look, otherwise, good luck :)